# Из двух строк введенных пользователем возвратить новую отсортированную строку в нижнем регистре

Tags: javascript, строки, сортировка, replace

Из двух строк, например "xY12aabbbcc:c"  и "xxx0xYYYYab;$$" которые вводит пользователь нужно вывести одну, что бы элементы строки не повторялись, были в нижнем регистре и отсортированы.В этой строке должны присутствовать только буквы.Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне исправить мой код?

```js
function string(form) {
  var firstString = form.first_string.value;
  var secondString = form.second_string.value;
  var firstPlusSecond = ((firstString + secondString).toLowerCase());
  var first_plus_second = unique(firstPlusSecond).replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "");

  function unique(arr) {
    var obj = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var str = arr[i];
      obj[str] = true;
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
  alert(first_plus_second);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="first_string">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="second_string">
    </p>
    <button type="button" onclick="string(form)">
   Match
  </button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для выполнения операций фильтрации и сортировки символов строку можно преобразовать в массив.

```js
function string(form) {
  var firstString = form.first_string.value
    , secondString = form.second_string.value
    , data = {};
  (firstString + secondString).toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').split('').forEach(function(c) {
    data[c] = true;
  });
  var result = Object.keys(data).sort().join('');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p><input type="text" name="first_string" value="xY12aabbbcc:c"></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="second_string" value="xxx0xYYYYab;$$"></p>
  <button type="button" onclick="string(form)">Match</button>
</form>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```